# Inflate a layout from an OnClick listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a class that extends from a Fragment, and I want to make a form inside that fragment. For that, I need to inflate differents layouts without moving out of the fragment. (Image for description, and code)

[image: When clicking in "Next", the app must go to the "step 2" BUT keep the "Denunciar" TAB from upside]

> When clicking in "Next", the app must go to the "step 2" BUT keep on the "Denunciar" tab from upside

I try doing this, but I don't know where is the mistake

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    ViewGroup container;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        Button buttonTab1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.botonTab1);
        buttonTab1.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.container = container;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you just set v variable as view which is inflated it has no sense

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak thank you for your response, what should I do to replace the inflated view whit the other I want?

Comment: As is describe in post below. Read about ViewPager and about FragmentManager and how to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all is not working because, your fragment only going to attached view to nutshell on `onCreateView()` method, and once view attached to window then for new View you have to redraw view again. And again If you can track the state of fragments based on condition what you have applied, you can detach and attach Fragment so it will create Fragment again which cause to call `onCreateView()` again now on some condition based you can change layout file.

To handle this either you can use Nested Fragments or ViewPager inside Fragments.

Some references:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested

Comment: A last question: it's possible to nest a fragment when the OnClick method is called?

Comment: @Villat - I have updated my answer, but can not suggest you to recreate fragment as it became complex to handle things.

Comment: @Villat - Yes, its same as other Fragment transaction.

Comment: Sorry, I have an issue now: I did what you say but now I have 1 fragment overlaying the first one, how can I do to let the new fragment override the first one?